# Не могу понять различия между 2 вариантами программы

Tags: java

```
static player scan_info_play() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//1 Variant
    player player__; String name; int num;
    while (true) {
        try {
            //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//2 Variant
            System.out.println("Введите данные игрока :\n");
            System.out.println("Имя :");
            name = in.next();
            System.out.println("Номер :");
            num = in.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("UNCORRECT DATA !");
            continue;
        }
    }
        player__ = new player(name, num, false);
        return player__;
```

[image: 1 variant][image: 2 variant]

В чем сам вопрос .. Когда я использую 1 вариант, то программа работает не корректно . Не могу понять почему после срабатывания ошибки и ее обработки , я возвращаюсь не на начало цикла с помощью оператора continue , а получается в средину . Почему оно мне выводит весь текст сначала , но не просит что бы я снова заполнил поле name (каким-то образом пропускает его )  спрашивает сразу номер , а не имя как в варианте 2 . Как я понимаю оно почему-то запоминает мой предыдущий ввод и не перезаписывает его   Как здесь влияет место объявления сканера но ход действий цикла ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом случае мы используем один и тот же Scanner, во втором случае, после каждой ошибки создаётся новый. Внутри Scanner устроен таким образом, что после считывания при помощи метода next или nextSomething, и в случае неудачи - сохранит то, что не удалось присвоить переменной после считывания - у себя. При следующем вызове метода next или nextSomething у одного и тоже же Scanner, старая информация будет пытаться присвоена следующей переменной, которой мы пытаемся вернуть результат метода next или nextSomething, и если тип данных подойдёт, то всё присвоится.

Например тут, поменяем местами порядом ввода name и number, next и nextInt, ошибёмся при вводе номера, то возникнет бесконечный цикл, 
который будет выбрасывать ошибку возвращаться в начало цикла, и пытаться присвоить ошибочно введённый данные не являющиеся int - переменной int, и.т.д:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scan_info_play();
    }
    static player scan_info_play() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//1 Variant
        player player__; String name; int num;
        while (true) {
            try {
                //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//2 Variant
                System.out.print("Data:\n");
                System.out.print("No:");
                num = in.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Na:");
                name = in.next();
                break;
            } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("UNCORRECT DATA !");
                continue;
            }
        }
            player__ = new player(num, name, false);
            return player__;
    }
}

class player {
    // Результат "[Бесконечный цикл]"
    player(int num, String name, boolean b){
        System.out.println(num + " " + name + " " + b);
    }
}
```

Во втором поменяем местами next и nextInt, сделаем как в вашем случае, ошибёмся при вводе int, неправильно введённые данные, которые должны были быть int, без труда присвоятся типу String в следующей итерации, после выполнения метода next();

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scan_info_play();
    }
    static player scan_info_play() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//1 Variant
        player player__; String name; int num;
        while (true) {
            try {
                //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//2 Variant
                System.out.print("Data:\n");
                System.out.print("Na:");
                name = in.next();
                System.out.print("No:");
                num = in.nextInt();
                break;
            } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("UNCORRECT DATA !");
                continue;
            }
        }
            player__ = new player(name, num, false);
            return player__;
    }
}

class player {
    player(String name, int num, boolean b){
        System.out.println(name + " " + num + " " + b);
        // Результат ["неправильно введённый в первый раз int", "int на второй итерации", "false"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Коротко:*
Нет очиски буфера в случаее генерации исключения в механизме Scaner.

*Чуть подробнее:*
Дело в устройстве самого механизма класса `Scaner`.
Если рассмотреть флоу процесса получения строки из импут стрима и так же каста оной к типу Integer вы увидете что валидация строки и последующая генерация исключения происходит без очискти буффера самого сканера.

И соответсвенно заходя потоком выполнения в следующий цикл итерации Вы автоматически применяете строку полученную для ввода числа к имени Вашего игрока.

Для Вашего случая в классе `Scaner` подойдет метод `reset()` хотя судя по сорсам самого метода это как минимум обернеться помимо сборска кеша и сбросом локали а это уже черевато другими интересными вопросами)

Не забывайте про дебаг)